# Styling of a table's row in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

My issue is very simple and I can't fugure it out as I'm not strong in styling... How to change the default **table row's height** using a css-in-js approach?

My first attempt was using a `material-ui`'s `Table` and it's `TableRow`:

```
const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        root: {
            height: '10px', // this doesn't work
        },
    }),
)(TableRow);
```

My second attempt was using a `mui-datatables`' `MUIDataTable`:

```
const getMuiTheme = (globalTheme: Theme) =>
        createMuiTheme({
            overrides: {
                //MUIDataTable {}, // I've found somewhere that that's a solution, but my package doen't recognize it
                MuiTableRow: {
                    root: {
                        height: '10px' // this doesn't work
                    },
                }
             }
          });

return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme(globalTheme)}>
            <MUIDataTable
                title={props.title}
                data={props.data}
                columns={props.columns}
                options={options}
            />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
```

If anyone has any pointers regarding any of these two - I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use materialui and put className in TableRow like this

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=>({
  tableRow: {
    height: 50,
  },
  }));

const classes = useStyles()

    

  <TableRow className={classes.tableRow}>
    ...
  </TableRow>
```

Comment: I need to stick to the approaches I've mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

In the table to set determine the height of the `TableRow`, two things need to be considered. One itself the height of the `TableRow` and the other is padding and height of the `TableCell`. `TableCell` has its own padding by default due to which after a certain limit the height of the `TableRow` doesn't reduce without removing that padding.

```
const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme) =>createStyles({
  root:{
    height:'20px',
  }
})
)(TableRow);
```

```
const StyledTablCell = withStyles((theme) =>createStyles({
  root:{
    backgroundColor:'yellow',
    padding:'0'
  }
})
)(TableCell);
```

Working demo:
[image: Edit blazing-currying-odo0c]